# Passing option id value to controller and retrieve from another blade view via onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

how do i pass my two option selected id to controller via onclick and retrieved it to another blade file

here is my code

option selected 1

```
  <select name="cu" id="cu" class="input-sm form-control" onchange="">
            <option value="">{{ __('messages.select') }}</option>

             @if(!empty($custList))
                                    @foreach($custList as $cu)
                                        <option value="{{ $cu->cu_customer_ID }}">{{ $cu->cu_customer_Shortname }}-{{ $cu->cu_customer_Name }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                @endif

                    </select>
```

option selected 2

```
 <select name="state" id="state" class="input-sm form-control">
            <option value="">{{ __('messages.select') }}</option>

                      @if(!empty(request()->session()->get('stateList')))
                                    @foreach(request()->session()->get('stateList') as $state)
                                        <option value="{{ $state->st_state_code }}">{{ $state->st_state_desc }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                @endif
                    </select>
```

onclick which both id value passing to controller

```
onclick="openNewWindow('{{ route('reporting.branchCheckBoxList', ['#cu' ,'#state']) }}')"
```

web route

```
Route::get('reporting/branchCheckBoxList/{cuid}/{stid?}','GenReportController@branchCheckBoxList')->name('reporting.branchCheckBoxList');
```

controller

```
 public function branchCheckBoxList($cuid, $stid = '') {

    $cuid = $cuid;
    $stid = $stid;

    return view('report.BranchCheckBoxList',  compact('cuid','stid'));
}
```

my another blade view

```
<script>
//how do i retrieve both selected value ??
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My ideal is fill a placeholder for params `cuid` and `stid` in `route` method and replace by selected value.

```
onclick="openNewWindow('{{ route('reporting.branchCheckBoxList', ['cuid' => '_cuid_', 'stid' => '_stid_']) }}'.replace('_cuid_', document.getElementById('cu').value).replace('_stid_', document.getElementById('state').value))"
```